# START variable of linked list loses its value after view did load

Tags: ios, xcode

I made a linked list and a global start variable for it. 
I am trying to access the same linked list from its start node in an other class but its value is lost after the `viewDidLoad` method. 
From `viewDidLoad` I am able to traverse the list but not from other methods..I guess its `autoreleasepool` in play how can I retain the start value of the start pointer?
 the node structure is

```
struct Movenode{
    NSMutableString *comment;
    NSMutableString *move;
    struct Movenode *variationLink;
    struct Movenode *nextLink;
    struct Movenode *goBack;
};


//viewDidLoad  Metod
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    myNode=START;
    While(myNode!=NULL)
    {
      NSLog(@"%@",myNode->move);
      myNode=myNode->nextLink;
    }
//it works fine here
}

-(void)otherMethod
{

myOtherNode=START;
while(myOtherNode!=NULL)
{
NSLog(@"%@",myOtherNode->move);//this line will give bad access there is no value in move.
myOtherNode=myOtherNode->nextLink;
}
}
```

Comment: Um, clarity please.  Is "linked list" a struct, or an array?  What is the "start node"? What is this talk of autoreleasepools?

Comment: i am using a structure (code given).The Start is a struct node* START variable which stores the address of the first node of linked list.It is accessible only in viewDidLoad method in rest its not though its global

Comment: I guess code speaks louder than words.  Please post these structs and viewDidLoad.

Comment: One last request: What does the declaration for the `START` variable look like?

Comment: struct node *START;  its in defines.h class i have included it in my pch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem by
1.insted of structure i used class.
2.i declared the START variable in app delegate.

using class allowed me to call retain on its objc i can now very well access the linked list from any where

thanku